# spinner drop down is overlapping on bottomnavigation view in constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner, android-constraintlayout

I have an activity in which I have bottomnavigationview and a fragment in constraint layout.
in one of the fragments I have dropdown spinner 
when I click on dropdown it overlaps with the bottom view

[image]

here is my activity code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.home.HomeActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change **width** and **height** of FrameLayout to "*match_constraint*" aka "*0dp*".

And also  don't forget to change **Left_toLeftOf** and **Right_toRightOf** to start/end.

Comment: Assuming your minimum sdk is 17+, there's no benefit to using left instead of start (or right instead of end), **but** there's also no penalty for using left+right as long as you're using them both together (and they're both identical).

Comment: Agreed. FrameLayout uses start/end and BottomNavigation uses left/righ - was just suggesting based on this.

Comment: i have changed it but still the same issue

Comment: Could you post full code of the layout ? This way we can't see the problem.